# Delete UITableViewCell and synchronize with Plist

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, plist

i have a class as

```
class DropOffFrequentVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    var googleDicCount : Int?
    var foursquareDicCount : Int?
    var favoriteGooglelocations  = [Int:GoogleItems]()
    var favoriteFourSquarelocations = [Int:FourSquareItems]()
```

i have a `UITableViewCell` as

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     .....

        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            cell.placeLbl.text = favoriteGooglelocations[indexPath.row]!.address
            cell.distanceLbl.text = favoriteGooglelocations[indexPath.row]!.distance
            cell.cityLbl.text =  favoriteGooglelocations[indexPath.row]!.name
            cell.favoriteBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            cell.favoriteBtn.addTarget(self, action: "DeleteGoogleFavorite:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            cell.favoriteBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()


        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

            cell.cityLbl.text = favoriteFourSquarelocations[indexPath.row]!.name
            cell.placeLbl.text = favoriteFourSquarelocations[indexPath.row]!.address
            cell.distanceLbl.text = favoriteFourSquarelocations[indexPath.row]!.distance
            cell.favoriteBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            cell.favoriteBtn.addTarget(self, action: "DeleteFourSquareFavorite:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            cell.favoriteBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        }

        return cell

    }
```

On those favoriteBtn action i want to delete the cell and code for this is as

```
 func DeleteGoogleFavorite(sender:UIButton){

  favoriteGooglelocations.removeValueForKey(sender.tag)
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String
    let path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Favorites.plist")
    let succeed = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(favoriteGooglelocations, toFile: path)
    println(succeed)
    loadFromPlist()
    self.tblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([sender.tag], withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
  }

func DeleteFourSquareFavorite(sender:UIButton){

    favoriteFourSquarelocations.removeValueForKey(sender.tag)
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String
    let path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("FourSquareFavorites.plist")
    let succeed = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(favoriteFourSquarelocations, toFile: path)
    println(succeed)
    loadFromPlist()
    self.tblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([sender.tag], withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)


}
```

*May be i have problem on those above methods..I dont know how to delete the UITableViewCell and update the plist as required..How do i acheive this?And the rest of the code is as below*

```
   func loadFromPlist(){


        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

        let documentDirectory = paths[0] as! String

        let  googleFavouritepath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Favorites.plist")

        var googleDic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(googleFavouritepath) as? [Int:GoogleItems]

        googleDicCount = googleDic?.count

        if(googleDic != nil){
            for (key,value) in googleDic!{
                let item = value

                println(item.name)
                println(item.address)

                var newLocation = GoogleItems()
                newLocation.name = item.name
                newLocation.address = item.address
                newLocation.distance = item.distance

                favoriteGooglelocations[key] = newLocation
               // self.locations.append(newLocation)

            }

        }

        let  foursquareFavouritepath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("FourSquareFavorites.plist")
        var fourSquareDic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(foursquareFavouritepath) as? [Int:FourSquareItems]
        foursquareDicCount = fourSquareDic?.count
        if(fourSquareDic != nil){
            for (key,value) in fourSquareDic!{
                let item = value
                println(item.name)
                println(item.address)
                println(item.isStar)

                var newLocation = FourSquareItems()
                newLocation.name = item.name
                newLocation.address = item.address
                newLocation.distance = item.distance
                favoriteFourSquarelocations[key] = newLocation
                //self.foursquarelocations.append(newLocation)

            }

        }

    }
```

i Have the following error on the line as

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        if section == 0{

            if let temp = googleDicCount{

                return googleDicCount! //this line gives me crash

            }else{

                return 0

            }

        }else if section == 1{
            if let temp = foursquareDicCount{

                return foursquareDicCount!

            }else{

                return 0

            }

        }

        return 1
    }
```

> GrabTaxi[603:9745] -[__NSCFNumber row]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0xb000000000000003 2015-06-08 09:30:18.045 GrabTaxi[603:9745]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber row]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'

Comment: perhaps you might have stored a `NSNumber` in `plist` as `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here

```
self.tblView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([sender.tag], withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

> sender.tag is not type of `NSIndexPath`

Right code should be

```
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: yoursection)//Here yoursection maybe 0 or 1,it depends on your function
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Not sure if you have other errors. Just try

Comment: thanks a lot..that was my real problem..one more question..is the way i am doing delete is good?

Comment: Every time you delete,you write all content to plist file and read from file. As you know, file access is much slower than memory access.But,if your data need to saved right now. That is just fine.